# How to redirect users to a different page if they aren't logged in? (ring/compojure)

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

what's the best way to route to one page if the user is signed in (i.e. session has a non-nil value for the `user-id` key) and another if the user is not signed in? The ideal would be 2 different set of routes.

Thanks!

Also, are there any good example apps using compojure out there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so figured this out. Routes in compojure are composable, so you can take a `defroutes` handlers and feed it to another `defroutes` handler.

http://vedang.me/techlog/2015/8/21/composability-and-compojure has a great explanation.